# Flag off-topic question that doesn't fit given options

Tags: discussion, flags, scope

I recently ran across a (since deleted) question by a new user asking for some UX feedback on a concept they were working on. There was no code involved; only high-level concepts. While the "primarily opinion-based" flag may have applied here, I think what would have really been the proper thing to do was to flag it to be moved to ux.stackexchange.com. Their question seemed likely to have actually gottten a useful answer had it been moved there. However, there are only 5 seemingly-random options to choose from:
[image: meta, superuser, tex, dba, and sharepoint]
There are dozens of sites in the Stack Excchange network, so I'm not sure why only 5 are available to choose from. There's also the "blatantly off-topic" flag, but this was a simple enough mistake to make ("I'm a programmer and I have a question -- better ask on StackOverflow"), so I don't think that flag applied. I ended up just moving on completely.

What would the recommended action have been to take here?

Comment: Flag it for moderator attention with a custom reason if it *really* deserves migration. If it's just going to be closed there as well, don't even bother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those choices are not random.  The Meta Stack Overflow option is there because some users may not know about it yet and the others have the highest success rate.  (The most questions that are put up for migration to those sites are actually migrated.)

First, if the question is inherently bad, do **not** migrate it.  Migration is only if the question is high quality but just is asked on the wrong site.  If it fits another close reason, close it as such and possibly *suggest* that the OP ask on another site after improving their question.

Otherwise, if the question would be a perfectly acceptable question on the other site and it is not listed in the migration choices, you can flag it for a moderator with the other flag.  Then, just explain what site it should be migrated to and why.  They should be able to migrate it if they agree.

Comment: Its not top 5 in terms of volume, but top 4 in terms of success rate + Meta.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  I'll correct that.